# Using twitter API get error sometimes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, twitter, twitter-oauth

I use the following code which works sometimes but its unstable , when I run the program sometimes I got error 420 with json parse error which doesnt give you lot of hints how to solve it. any idea what am I doing wrong ?

The error is :

> Error getting tweets: Error: Status Code: 420 Error getting tweets:
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0

```
var Twitter=require('twitter');
var lclconf = require('../config.json');


var client=new Twitter({
  consumer_key: lclconf.twitter.consumer_key,
  consumer_secret: lclconf.twitter.consumer_secret,
  access_token_key: lclconf.twitter.access_token_key,
  access_token_secret: lclconf.twitter.access_token_secret
});
stream.on("data", function(data){
  console.log(data.id_str);
  var tweet_id="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/oembed.json?id="+data.id_str;
  request.get(tweet_id)
  .end(function(err,res){
      if(err){
        console.log("Error from Twitter API: " + err);
      }else{
        //console.log(res.body);
        io.emit('tweet',res.body);
      }
  });
});
stream.on('error', function(err){
  console.log("Error getting tweets: "+err);
});
io.on('connection', function(client){
  client.on("join", function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
  client.emit("join",{"message":"running"});
});
```

Maybe if there is a way that when the error is occurred ignore it and proceed since now the process is stopped.

**Update:**

In twitter docs there is info about HTTP 420 but not sure how to fix it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per **pii_ke**'s response you should simply modify `tweet_id` as follows:

```
var tweet_id = "https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=https://twitter.com/" + data.user.screen_name + "/statuses/" + data.id_str;
```

Full modified code you can copy paste:

```
var Twitter=require('twitter');
var lclconf = require('../config.json');


var client=new Twitter({
  consumer_key: lclconf.twitter.consumer_key,
  consumer_secret: lclconf.twitter.consumer_secret,
  access_token_key: lclconf.twitter.access_token_key,
  access_token_secret: lclconf.twitter.access_token_secret
});
stream.on("data", function(data){
  console.log(data.id_str);
  var tweet_id = "https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=https://twitter.com/" + data.user.screen_name + "/statuses/" + data.id_str;
  request.get(tweet_id)
  .end(function(err,res){
      if(err){
        console.log("Error from Twitter API: " + err);
      }else{
        //console.log(res.body);
        io.emit('tweet',res.body);
      }
  });
});
stream.on('error', function(err){
  console.log("Error getting tweets: "+err);
});
io.on('connection', function(client){
  client.on("join", function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
  client.emit("join",{"message":"running"});
});
```

Comment: Thanks I try it but I got the same erorr :( , any other idea?

Answer (score 6):

[HTTP 420 is returned when you are being rate limited.](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes)

There is a [`https://publish.twitter.com/oembed` resource URL](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/oembed), that is neither rate limited nor requires authentication. I think it returns the same things that your program expects. You can use that if you pass a query parameter `url` having the link to tweet. Try making the link like:

```
"https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=https://twitter.com/"+data.user.screen_name+"/statuses/"+data.id_str
```

For sample data returned by Twitter click [here](https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FInterior%2Fstatus%2F507185938620219395)

Comment: Thanks, but not sure how to do it with your example, can you provide the complite example with my code ?

Comment: I do not program in Javascript much. I can see how to create `Twitter` and `client` objects in your code, but I am not sure about the objects `request`, `stream`, and `io`. If you tell how to create these then I can test something. @shopiaT